# trying to give role for voter top.gg

Tags: discord, discord.js, webhooks

i'm trying to give top.gg voters role in my server but there's so many thing happened got me confused and i can't find any solution for it.

full source code : https://sourceb.in/dSlb2nhjPH

here's my code :

```js
app.post('/vote', webhook.listener(vote => {

    client.users.fetch(vote.user).then(user => {
        console.log(`Found ${user.tag}.`);
        let role = client.guilds.cache.get('928290243843604500').roles.cache.get("942061236475002952")
        user.roles.add(role).catch(e => { console.log('Something went wrong, i cant add roles') })
        
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("Couldn't find the user.");
    });

}))
```

so after someone vote the console log showing this:

```js
Found ' Ab#2000.
Couldn't find the user.
```

which mean there's something wrong it showing the user found and showing his tag
but didn't give the role to the user then just showing Couldn't find the user.

i hope someone could help with this i have been trying to setup custom vote system for a while

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a role to a **User**. You need to fetch the User by ID as a **GuildMember** in a particular guild, then you can add role to that member.
Like-

```
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("guildID")
const role = guild.roles.cache.get("roleID")
const member = guild.members.cache.get(vote.user)
if (!member) return;
member.roles.add(role).then(() => ...).catch(err => ...)
```